# How to add an mvc page to umbraco

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have Umbraco 7.5 and I need to know how to create normal MVC pages for adding new data to my site.

Lets say I have a Doctype "Node" in back-office. I want to let some people be able to add/edit some nodes without going through back-office. How can I do it?

I've tried to create add my view and controller (the MVC way), but apparently Umbraco hijacks all routing and my controller won't hit at all.

I've googled the matter (which is hard since I am not looking for Umbraco forms :| )and I've found [this](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/getting-started/Code/Creating-Forms/). But I prefer not to add my form as a part of other page. I mean, does it make sense to create a page in back office from type "something" and then on its template I do my add/edit form of another type? Seems strange, right?

I appreciate any ideas/ solution to this matter

Comment: Take a look at the routing documentation https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/routing/custom-controllers

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options here. You can create a physical page for the editor to sit on, and add the editor as a SurfaceController action (basically an MVC Partial with Postback, that is still part of the Umbraco pipeline). Your form can then use the Content Service API to update the details. The advantage of this method is your code will have access to all of the Umbraco methods and templating out of the box. You could also use WebAPI controllers for the form if you want to do it all client side with JS requests.

You could also use route hijacking: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/routing/custom-controllers this allows you to have your own custom controllers for Umbraco routes, rather than using the default Umbraco ones. This is a bit more work to set up.

Finally, you can also tell Umbraco to ignore certain paths entirely, and you could run your controllers on those paths. The disadvantage here is that as the routes are being ignored by Umbraco, you don't automatically have access to all the useful Umbraco templating etc.

I've used the first method recently, and it works fine. The only caveat is that allowing users to edit nodes will fill up the version table quite quickly if a lot of users are editing a lot of nodes (every time a node is saved, a version is created). If you're going down this route, you may want to investigate something like Unversion: https://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/unversion/ which helps to keep old versions more manageable in situations like this.